# Tool to aid/assist in refactoring force.com code base (renaming custom objects)

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

We need to rename about 15 custom objects in a force.com.

In Java, this would be a right click and about 20 minutes work, but given the number of soql queries, classes, pages, profiles etc that use these object, we're looking at a week, two weeks... or more.

So, ideally, we're looking for a refactoring tool which will help us rename this objects and resolve any interdependencies.

Force.com IDE naturally, doesn't support this.   Any ideas/tools/approaches?

Comment: Good luck with that. Salesforce is notoriously difficult when it comes to large scale changes like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did that with two objects and it was a royal pain, I can image 15 poses quite a challenge. As you noticed by now salesforce constructs are highly interdependent with cross, even circular references being legit. THis on the other hand makes tear-down and core modification very difficult and virtually impossible to automate.

What you can do is following:

> 1. Use sandbox for modifications, do an inventory of all constructs using
>      affected objects. You can use Ctrl-H
>      to search the entire workspace in IDE
> 2. On sandbox, clone those 15 objects into their respective future names,
>      they'll be empty but who cares on
>      sandbox.
> 3. Now that you have objects in place, rename all mentions in all constructs
>      from #1 to use new objects
> 4. Just to make sure try to delete old objects
>      from sandbox, this will serve as a
>      sanity check that you didn't miss any
>      dependency.
> 5. Off work hours delete the entire inventory of #1 from production server, leaving just bare objects with their data
> 6. Now that the dependencies are gone, rename all 15 objects
> 7. In one session deploy the entire modified inventory from sandbox to
>      production, since the payload now uses
>      new object names the tests should
>      pass.

I dont think it should take you more than a day for all this.